# There is a way to list Google Meet URL from an event Google Calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to list in a Spreadsheet all the Google Meet URL that was generated to each event that belong to an specific calendar un Google Calendar.

Currently I'm able to create events in Google Calendar using Apps Script, but also I need to save the URL that was generated. I thought that there was a way of getting it, but I found nothing :(

I hope some of you now how to do this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Calendar API method [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) returns you an [Event Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) that contains among others the property `hangoutLink`

This can be implemented in Apps Script as:

```
var myLink = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).hangoutLink;
```

> Mind that `Calendar` opposed to `CalendarApp` is an Advanced Service
>   that needs to be [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)